# Why does Cicero change gear in this example from the Catiline Orations?

Tags: cicero, rhetoric

In Cic, Catil. 2.3.5 there is:

> "hos quos video volitare in foro, quos stare ad curiam, quos etiam in senatum venire, qui nitent unguentis, qui fulgent purpura, mallem secum suos milites eduxisset;" the translation (C.D. Yonge, 1856):

> "I wish he had taken with him those soldiers of his, whom I see hovering about the Forum, standing about the Senate house, even coming into the Senate, who shine with ointment, who glitter in purple;".

Cicero expresses his contempt for the acolytes of Catiline (his soldiers) in indirect (accusative-infinitive) speech: "quos volitare"; "quos stare"; "quos venire"; then, he switches to subordinate clauses: "qui nitent"; "qui fulgent".

Why not continue in the full-flow of indirect speech, completing this tour-de-force with "quos nitere" & "quos fulgere"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This interesting syntactic *variatio* you point out is probably related to the fact that the three infinitival constructions refer to three SPATIAL events WITNESSED by Cicero, who was also THERE. Note also that each spatial verb has its locative or directional complement: *volitare in foro*, *stare ad curiam*, and *in senatum venire*. The two following predicates are not spatial but refer to a different semantic type: *nitent unguentis* and *fulgent purpura* are, let's say, ornament predicates. So this grammatical *variatio* you point out can be said to run parallel to (or, to put it more strongly, to be motivated by) meaning & style differences. As noted, Cicero preferred to construe himself as witnessing (cf. *video*) the three *spatial* events in order to emphasize that he was also *there*! So this pragmatic meaning is the really relevant one here.

This said, as you rightly note, there would be nothing grammatically wrong with putting the following two non-spatial predicates in infinitive, i.e. in tune with the three spatial ones, making then all of them dependent on *video*. So, if your question is whether there is a grammatical or syntactic reason that accounts for the *variatio* found in the text, the answer is negative. It is rather a matter of (mainly, pragmatic) meaning & style.

Comment: Relatedly, the three infinitival phrases denote actions, while the finite verbs denote states; and the actions (unlike the states) are ones that immediately threaten the republic, which helps explain the pragmatic importance of *video*: "Look, his soldiers are right there, I can see them now!" It would be less rhetorically appropriate to say "I see them shining and glittering", as the "here and now" aspect of those states is not situationally relevant in the same way.

Comment: @TKR I agree. BTW, I deliberately avoided discussing the complex issue of their Aktionsart properties since _volitare_ & _venire_ are more dynamic than _stare_ (NB: 'stand' has been (mis)described as a stative verb). As for the stativity of _nitere_ and _fulgere_ (and other similar verbs: cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8848/aret-aridus-est ), they express D(avidsonian)-states, i.e. those states that have an event argument:  Cf. "I see them _shining_" (D-state) vs. * "I see them _being tall_" (Kimian state). See https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4020-6197-4_4

Comment: @TKR So note that from a lexical-aspectual perspective, it could be the case that, to the extent that _stare_ is also a Davidsonian state (see the 2nd link above for Maienborn's (2008) claim that "stand" is a D-state), it would go with _nitere_ and _fulgere_ rather than with _vol(it)are_ and _venire_, which express proper events (cf. your descriptive term "action").